# Route name returns 404 despite working view

Tags: 8, views, hooks, breadcrumbs

I'm assigning breadcrumbs based on the view route names using the following code in `hook_preprocess_breadcrumb()`.

```php
$route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
if ($route_name == 'view.news_list.main') {
  // Declare breadcrumbs.
}
```

My problem occurs with one of my views. For some reason, getting the route on the view returns *system.404* despite the view being shown correctly. Why is this happening?

I forgot to say the view is set to the front page. For some reason, that's when the error started. Site is also multilingual, Japanese being the default.

Comment: Do you have any specific configuration for this one view? Like access resctrictions or contextual filters and if so, does your issue appear for specific values only (/example/1/2) or for any values?

Comment: @misterdidi No contextual filters, relationships, or access restrictions, just normal filter criteria.

Comment: Does your view preview work?
If yes, comment the code for breadcrumb and check whether the view displays or not.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Where did you put that code? What is the exact string the code is using in `if ($route_name == 'this route name') { /* */ }`? I doubt you are looking for a route whose name is *this route name*.

Comment: @apaderno Thanks for the welcoming! I put the code in hook_preprocess_breadcrumb in my theme file. The exact string code is `$route_name == 'view.news_list.main'`. I used the code above just as a placeholder.

Comment: @Meera Yes, the view preview works. The view displays as well. My problem is that the route name returns system.404 despite the page rendering correctly.